# equivalent of $\frac{(n+1)^{\frac{n+1}{n}}-(n-1)^{\frac{n-1}{n}}}{n}$

Tags: calculus

The aim is to prove that $u_n=\frac{(n+1)^{\frac{n+1}{n}}-(n-1)^{\frac{n-1}{n}}}{n}$ is equivalent to $2\frac{\ln n}{n}$.

By using standard estimations, my book obtains that

$u_n=\frac{e^{\ln n}}{n}\left(e^{\frac{\ln n}{n}+o(\frac{\ln n}{n})}- e^{-\frac{\ln n}{n}+o(\frac{\ln n}{n})}\right)$

I don't understand the following : they write that the previous expression is equal to

$\frac{2\ln n}{n} + o(\frac{\ln n}{n})$. Why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have that

$$u_n=\frac{e^{\ln n}}{n}\left(e^{\frac{\ln n}{n}+o(\frac{\ln n}{n})}- e^{-\frac{\ln n}{n}+o(\frac{\ln n}{n})}\right)=e^{\frac{\ln n}{n}+o(\frac{\ln n}{n})}- e^{-\frac{\ln n}{n}+o(\frac{\ln n}{n})}$$

and

$$e^{\frac{\ln n}{n}+o(\frac{\ln n}{n})}=1+\frac{\ln n}{n}+o\left(\frac{\ln n}{n}\right)$$

$$e^{-\frac{\ln n}{n}+o(\frac{\ln n}{n})}=1-\frac{\ln n}{n}+o\left(\frac{\ln n}{n}\right)$$

Comment: Thanks ! I get it.

Comment: @trocho You are welcome! Bye